# MAX function and group by usage - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am building a ranking algorithm using IMDB's formula:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411199/what-is-a-better-way-to-sort-by-a-5-star-rating/1411268#1411268

```
The formula for calculating the Top Rated 250 Titles gives a true Bayesian estimate:

weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C

where:

* R = average for the movie (mean) = (Rating)
* v = number of votes for the movie = (votes)
* m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 250 (currently 1300)
* C = the mean vote across the whole report (currently 6.8)
for the Top 250, only votes from regular voters are considered.
```

The problem I am having is that I am not sure how to get the AVG and MAX from the whole result set. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/054e2/3)

I am guessing it has to do with the `GROUP BY` clause.

Also, how can I set "business 4" ranking to 0 instead of null?

Comment: If you don't use `GROUP BY`, you will get the aggregates for all the rows selected (as specified by the `WHERE` clause).  In this case you can't specify other columns in the `SELECT` list.  If you say `GROUP BY id`, aggregates will be computed for any values of id, in your case for single rows - that's useless.

Comment: What if I want to SELECT other columns though?

Comment: If there are multiple values for a column within a group which value do you want to select? If you are certain that the columns you want to select have the same values when grouped by id add them to the group by clause

Comment: I suspect you either want a *subquery* to get the dataset-wide mean and max, or to use `avg` and `max` as *window functions* to do both resultset-wide and per-group results.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started:

```
select name,
       (reviews_count / reviews_count + max_reviews_count) * rating + (max_reviews_count / (reviews_count+max_reviews_count) * avg_rating) AS ranking
from (
  SELECT name,
         reviews_count,
         rating, 
         MAX(reviews_count) over () as max_reviews_count,
         AVG(rating) over() as avg_rating
  FROM businesses
) t;
```

Note that I removed the nullif to make it easier to read.

I'm not sure the use of the window functions is totally correct. I guess you need to do some grouping in there. If that is the case, then add this to the `over()` clause, e.g. `over(partition by name)`

The `partition by` in a window function is essentially a `group by` without the need to group the whole result.

For more details on window functions, please see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html